# Greek letter version of $U$?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Wondering if there is any math symbol for the greek letter $U$? I know $\mu$. Any similiar looking symbol that I can draw in latex?

Comment: Try `$\upsilon$`.

Comment: also `$\Upsilon$`

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Tex are you looking for a different style µ symbol?

Like here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ upgreek }

\begin{document}
    
$\mu$
$\upmu$
$\upsilon$ %see Werner´s comment
$\Upsilon$
$U$
$\cup$

\end{document}
```

[image]